How to make a matte screen glossy safely?
99% of ideal-for-gaming monitors have some level of matte finish to them that hazes the display slightly. Even some fantastic art monitors ruin a perfect display by hazing it. Which loses sharpness and is sad if you work in controlled lighting and don't have a reflection problem.
I have seen videos where some people remove the protective layer from their image layer to get it glossy, which is pretty crazy, because:

You can ruin the unprotected surface if the matte layer doesn't come off well, and…
If you have someone who cleans your desk for you and doesn't know to be careful with the unprotected screen they could damage it easily with something as simple as furniture polish on their dusting cloth.

I really don't want to do this so I spent 20 hours searching for a good gaming monitor (things like 24" - not so big you have to look around when you are sitting 2 foot away - and 1440p to keep the sharpness up, and decent colour etc.) and I could not find ONE except for a very risky new Korean company which might be re-selling Dell rejects.
I even thought of pouring some kind of silicone sealant over the screen to fill out the microscopic bumps in the matte finish, but it's unlikely to set perfectly smoothly and very variable in expected result.
Then I thought of ordering 100 monitors to spec and selling 99... but no one's offering that either for custom monitors.
So it seemed like an insoluble problem.

But then I thought of a safe solution that actually works!! It reduces the haze by at least 95%. So you don't have to destroy your monitor by removing the matte layer.
Just apply a second protective layer, a glossy one!
In my test case I used one called Vivid from Viascreens.
The two layers merged seamlessly, the adhesive filling the rough finish of the matte, combining to make a very slightly thicker protective glossy layer, reducing the haze by at least 95%.
It works like a charm!
My brightness was not affected at all by the tiny increase in protective layer, and the screen really pops now.

It's just occurred to me that you can apply this concept in reverse, to turn your glossy screen matte, or even semi-glossy (4% haze).
Just apply the appropriate protective layer for the level of matte you desire.

As long as the screen protector has a soft adhesive layer that can move and fill in the texturing then this is the least destructive advice. This was actually a thing with the top end Steam Deck which has an anti-glare matt finish, people were complaining that by putting a screen protector on they lost the matt finish. https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamDeck/comments/te3y8d/steam_deck_screen_comparison_512gb_vs/  it may not be perfect, and might depend on how deep the matt finish is etched as well as how well the screen protector is applied, but this is a valid method.
